# EntityFramework update-database multiple databasecontexts adding table not creating database

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have two separate database contexts and expect to have a database for each database context.
When I do entityfirst migrations why is it not creating separate databases?
Instead, one of the database contexts is creating a table inside of the other context even though I am specifying the -context parameter explicitly.

appsetting.json

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"BuildAppDb": "Server=DESKTOP-BJR3FMP\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=EasyBuilderApp;Trusted_Connection=True;",
"LicenseKeyDb": "Server=DESKTOP-BJR3FMP\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=EstiframeSoftwareLicenser;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

},

contexts

```
    public partial class BuildAppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public BuildAppDbContext(DbContextOptions<BuildAppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }


    public DbSet<PartCompletion> PartCompletions { get; set; }
}

public class LicenseKeyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public LicenseKeyDbContext(DbContextOptions<LicenseKeyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<LicenseReg> RegLicenses { get; set; }

}
```

startup.cs
Configuring services

```
//DATABASE CONNECTIONS
        string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("LicenseKeyDb");
        services.AddDbContext<LicenseKeyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("BuildAppDb");
        services.AddDbContext<BuildAppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

package manager console commands

```
add-migration -context BuildAppDbContext
update-database -context BuildAppDbContext
add-migration -context LicenseKeyDbContext
update-database -context LicenseKeyDbContext
```

RESULT ?? WHY

It is adding a table to the EasyBuilderApp database when it should be adding an entire database for the EstiframeSoftwareLicenser database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem.

I literally had to use a separate string variable here:

.AddDbContext method is executed later, not at that exact moment so using the same variable to store the connection string does not work.

[image]